# Sum of $1/[(n + 1)^2] + 1/[(n + 2)^2] + ... + 1/[(2n)^2]$ when n goes to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Could someone please help me understand the steps to solve this problem?

Comment: Wait... so you are interested specifically in $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$?  Well... the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges... so...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+ \frac{1}{(2n)^2} + … + \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + … + \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \leq\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}+ … + \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\frac{n}{(2n)^2} \lt s_n \lt \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$.

Answer (score -1):

For finite $n$ the sum is $\psi ^{(1)}(n+1)-\psi ^{(1)}(2 n+1)$, where $\psi$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).  Take the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \psi ^{(1)}(n+1)-\psi ^{(1)}(2 n+1) \right) = 0.$$

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to pull out the polygamma function here.  To a beginner student, unnecessary information and notation can do more harm than good and just confuse them.

Comment: The OP has a reputation of 1 and is clearly a beginner. Do you really think your answer has a bat in hell's chance of helping him or her?